POWER BI What is causing the circular dependency?
I am trying to create a new table called 'daily_rainfall' in Power BI with 5 columns: city, total_rainfall_3months_ago, total_rainfall_2months_ago, total_rainfall_last_month, total_rainfall_this_month. The rainfall columns will be calculated using the 'rainfall' column from the 'database' table. They are related through the 'city' column.
I inserted the first column (city_name) and used the "New Column" option to add the 'total_rainfall_3months_ago'. The DAX code used is the following:
PPT_3 = 
VAR TotalRainfall = 
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(database[rainfall]),
        database[year] = YEAR(TODAY()),
        database[month] = MONTH(TODAY()) - 3 
    )

RETURN 
    TotalRainfall

But when i try to create any of the other columns (total_rainfall_last_month for example) i get the following error message "A circular dependency was detected: daily_rainfall[Coluna], daily_rainfall[PPT_0], daily_rainfall[Coluna]."
Here is the code i'm using:
PPT_1 = 
VAR TotalRainfall = 
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(database[rainfall]),
        database[year] = YEAR(TODAY()),
        database[month] = MONTH(TODAY()) - 1 
    )

RETURN 
    TotalRainfall

I don't understand what is causing the circular dependency neither how to fix it.

https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/avoiding-circular-dependency-errors-in-dax/

I tried switching to Measures instead of Calculated Columns and it fixed the circular dependency issue but raised another: i need to be able to define the Summarization (change from Sum to Mean) but it can't be done in Measures. I added the ALLEXCEPT term to deal with the circular dependency as the link posted in @davidebacci 's response suggested, it fixed the circular dependency issue but now it returns a single value for all cities instead of doing the calculations for each city. How could i fix this?
